# Wht cannot this term be equal to zero?

Tags: calculus, quadratics, tangent-line

I came across the following problem:

```
   For y=x³, tangent at A meets the curve again at B. 
   Gradient at B is k times the gradient at A. Then the 
   number of integral values of k is:
```

I proceeded as:-

Let A (a,y1) and B (b,y2) **for all real x**

The slope of tangent at B = (a³-b³)/(a-b)

And we know that slope of tangent at A, that is, 3a² = K times slope at B

So, process this information, I got the following quadratic equation:

```
      (3-K)(b/a)² - K(b/a) - K = 0
```

Since x is real, the discriminant of the above equation has to be greater than or equal to zero. Processing it I got:

```
        K belongs to the interval [0,4]
```

So the answer came out to be 5, since we need the integral values. But in the answer key, it is given that k cannot be zero, thus making the answer 3.

My question is why can't K be zero? Am I missing something?

*Please note that a similar question has been asked by someone, but the answer is not at all satisfactory. Thus, please refrain from providing any links to that answer*

Comment: "thus making the answer 3" - how can the answer be $3$ values, if $[0,4]$ contains $4$ nonzero integers?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde that is what I am unable to understand. The solution to this implies that k cannot be zero.

Comment: No, I mean your answer then should be $5$ (and not $4$), because $0,1,2,3,4$ are five values in $[0,4]$. The answer seems to be indeed $4$, and not $3$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3186485/for-y-x3-tangent-at-a-meets-the-curve-again-at-b-gradient-at-b-is-k-times?rq=1).

Comment: I apologise that I made a mistake there. So the answer cannot be 3, but seems to be 4. But the reasoning, that K cannot be zero...is it correct?

Comment: $K=0$ would imply zero gradient at $B$. Do you see what this means?

Comment: The tangent in $x=a$, namely $y-a^3=3a^2(x-a)$ meets the function in $x=-2a$.  Now $f'(a)=3a^2$ and $f'(-2a)=12a^2=4\cdot f'(a)$ hence $k=1$ for any value of $a$. -- Am I missing something?

Comment: "Please note that a similar question has been asked by someone, but the answer is not at all satisfactory. Thus, please refrain from providing any links to that answer." That's not how it works. [The other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3186485/139123) is relevant and people answering this question should be aware of it. You may add to your question to explain why you think the answer there is unsatisfactory. In fact, the answer to the other question is completely correct, and it shows that the answer key you read is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The equation of the tangent line at $A = (a,a^3)$ is

$$ y - a^3 = 3a^2 (x - a).$$

Since this passes through $B = (b,b^3)$ we have

$$b^3 - a^3 = 3a^2 (b - a).$$

This equation can be rewritten as

$$(b -a)^2(b + 2a) = 0.$$

Since $b \ne a$, we have $b = -2a$, whenever $a \ne 0$. If $a = 0$, then according to the terms of the question, there is no corresponding value of $b$.

We have $3b^2 = 4(3a^2)$. Thus $k$ can take only one value, namely $4$.

Comment: As pointed out in my comment ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe In all honesty, I hadn't seen your comment and finished writing my answer about 45 seconds after that, but thanks for pointing this out. In your comment, I don't understand why you say that $k = 1$. Could you explain?

Comment: It's alright.  The OP asked for *the number of integral values*.  And there's only one integral value, namely $4$.

Answer (score 0):

One reason $k$ cannot be zero is that "zero times the gradient at $A$" is zero,
that is, $k=0$ implies the gradient at $B$ is zero,
which can be true only if $B = (0,0).$
But there is no tangent to the curve $y = x^3$ that passes through $(0,0),$
so $(0,0)$ cannot be the point at which the tangent at $A$ meets the curve again.

Another reason $k$ cannot be zero is that $k = 4,$ a fact that has been proved already [in another answer to your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4229122/139123) and in [For $y=x^3$, tangent at A meets the curve again at B. Gradient at B is $k$ times the gradient at A.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3186485/139123)
This fact also proves that the answer key you read the answer "$3$" from is wrong.
The *number of integral values of $k$* is $1$.
(That is, there is only one possible value of $k,$ and that value happens to be an integer.)

By the way, I count at least three errors in your working.
It is remarkable that you got a result as close to the answer key as you did.